# Android studio 1.2.2 gradle library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Adding a gradle project with compile has been working for me very well, but I noticed after updating the Android studio to 1.2.2, or maybe the version just before it, that adding a library is not working anymore.

So for example I tried to add [this](https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress) and I did the "Sync Now" and it was successful but the library doesn't seem to be recognized. When I try to use ProgressWheel in Java and I hit ctrl+Enter it doesn't find the library, anyone have an idea of what should I do?

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
    //the above libraries were added before the update, everything was 
    //working fine, the below isn't 
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
   }
```

Please note that I tried many other libraries and all had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The project README (front page of https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress) says it's on **Maven Central**. Android Studio uses **jCenter** (by Bintray) by default. Add this in your module's `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Same thing, and why doesn't syncing complain about it btw?

Comment: @AdroidFreak odd. It works perfectly fine for me if I add it to one of my projects. Why doesn't it complain that it can't find it? There's millions of Maven repositories out there, there's no way it could know where it is; all that it can know is that it doesn't exist in any repositories it's given.

Comment: I also tried this which I used to use actually and it's not working https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView

Comment: @AdroidFreak there must be something wrong with your project setup or computer.

Comment: @AdroidFreak on a side note, why are you using libraries for this rather than Google's AppCompat?

Comment: Do you have a working a circular progress sample using AppCompat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83907/discussion-between-adroid-freak-and-afollestad).